# Jquery - If cursor position at the start/end in a textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, selection, textselection

i have a textarea and I want to check if the cursor is at the start or at the end (I dont need the current position).
 Did anybody know a simple jQuery solution?

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: Do you mean `<input type="text">` or a `<textarea>`?

Comment: I mean <input type="text">. Is textbox the current word?

Comment: Guess so. I'm never certain what people mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you mean a `<input type="text">` rather than a textarea, here's a non-jQuery solution (that you can still use with your jQuery code). It will almost certainly be less code than a jQuery plug-in.

**UPDATE 12 November 2011**

Having said that, I have developed [a jQuery plug-in](https://github.com/timdown/rangyinputs) for just his kind of task, and it is indeed bigger than the code below.

```
var textInput = document.getElementById("your_id"), val = textInput.value;
var isAtStart = false, isAtEnd = false;
if (typeof textInput.selectionStart == "number") {
    // Non-IE browsers
    isAtStart = (textInput.selectionStart == 0);
    isAtEnd = (textInput.selectionEnd == val.length);
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    // IE <= 8 branch
    textInput.focus();
    var selRange = document.selection.createRange();
    var inputRange = textInput.createTextRange();
    var inputSelRange = inputRange.duplicate();
    inputSelRange.moveToBookmark(selRange.getBookmark());
    isAtStart = inputSelRange.compareEndPoints("StartToStart", inputRange) == 0;
    isAtEnd = inputSelRange.compareEndPoints("EndToEnd", inputRange) == 0;
}

alert("At start: " + isAtStart + ", at end: " + isAtEnd);
```

Comment: Is this answer still valid as of Jan 2016?

Comment: @Jessica: Absolutely, and it will almost certainly be valid for the foreseeable future since `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are [standardized](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-textarea/input-selectionstart). The second branch is only for IE 8 and earlier so could be removed if you don't need to worry about those browsers.

Comment: Thanks! Do you suggest I support IE 8 and earlier?

Comment: @Jessica: That really depends on your audience but in general I'd say not, particularly since Microsoft themselves have [recently stopped supporting older versions of IE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support).

Answer (score 2):

**Yep, use this [awesome jQuery plugin](http://laboratorium.0xab.cd/jquery/fieldselection/0.1.0/test.html).**

*Need more info? Come back here with more questions :)*

**Update**
The original blog post associated with the plugin is down.

Thanks to the **Awesome Power** of the wayback machine, you can still view it.

http://web.archive.org/web/20080620163228/http://blog.0xab.cd/jquery-plugin---fieldselection

**God I love that website.**

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for the fast answer!

Comment: No worries @Peter, I hope the plugin helps :)

Comment: Can you give me a little example how to use? The page "http://blog.0xab.cd/jquery-plugin---fieldselection"  is unfortunately down :(

Comment: @Peter - see my update. You can view the blog post using the Wayback machine.

Comment: Wayback machine, nice idea ^^. Thanks!